# In Rubymotion how to get callback from dismissed view controller

Tags: rubymotion, formotion

On a table row click I reference a cell to present a view controller (to select from a list of images)

```
  def open_selector             
     view_b = ImagesController.new  #using rmq hence .new           
     @@cell.superview.superview.controller.presentViewController view_b, animated:true, completion:nil
  end
```

Inside the images controller - I dismiss when finished selecting - but how do I let cell know it was closed?

```
def collectionView(view, didSelectItemAtIndexPath: index_path)

  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: lambda{})

end
```

Comment: Typical..figured it out a few minutes later. Basically you set delegate = self from View1, and call method on delegate from View2.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest providing your `UICollectionViewController` a delegate so it can call back itself. So:

```
class MyCollectionViewController < UICollectionViewController
  attr_writer :parent_controller

  # ...

  def collectionView(view, didSelectItemAtIndexPath: index_path)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, 
                                       completion: lambda{
                                       @parent_controller.collection_did_close(self)
                                       })
  end
```

Assuming, you have a method called `collection_did_close` in the parent controller, it will be called with a reference to the collection view controller. Using that you can grab whatever information you need out of there before it gets garbage collected.